# How to unversion file in git and still keep it

Tags: git

Let's say I have a file with passwords, I blank them out and then do commit/push. After that I would like for git to stop updating that file, since I will be putting in my passwords back in my local git repo, I don't want to have to remove them every time I do a commit/push.

Is there a way to unversion a file in git but still keep it?

My repo structure is like this:

```
> my-repo
    > folder1
        > ... other stuff
    > folder2
        > ... other stuff
    > folder3            
        > ... other stuff
        > launch.sh
```

I opened up .git/info/exclude and added this (last) line:

```
# git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
# Lines that start with '#' are comments.
# For a project mostly in C, the following would be a good set of
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):
# *.[oa]
# *~
folder3/launch.sh
```

But nothing happens, git keeps versioning the file and all my changes to it, so when i add back the password, it shows up in git diff.

Comment: Not sure if this is the best solution, but what I do is add the file to the gitignore (but I don't commit it).

Comment: I can do that, but the syntax would be the same. I did not use .gitignore because that would set it globally for all my repos.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities:

The better option is to `git mv passwords.conf passwords.conf.example` and then add `passwords.conf` to `.gitignore`. That is, don't put the actual passwords file in the git repo, just a template that can be used when people configure their installation. Your setup script might do a conditional copy here.

The worse option is to use `git update-index --assume-unchanged`. But seriously, please don't. Among other reasons, because you also have to teach this to every single person cloning your repo.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the file to be there, modify it, and have git ignore the changes, use `git update-index --assume-unchanged $file`

However, an important detail: if your passwords are in the git repository currently, removing them and committing isn't enough. They will remain in the git history. You will need to clean the whole history. See https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

Something important: if those passwords were ever part of the history of a publicly accessible repository, even for one second, consider them compromised and change them as soon as possible.

Comment: Also, please see o11c's response above. He has a great point regarding other users of your repository not necessarilly remembering not to commit the sensitive file. Better have a .example file that can be copied.